# How to connect DLT Viewer to the Target via CLI command

Tags: dlt

I try to automate my processes and need to connect DLT Viewer to the Target via CLI command.

I can open DLT Viewer via CLI command below, but I cannot make it connected.

```
dlt_viewer -s -p Trial_Proj_File.dlp -l Trial_Log.dlt
```

Comment: Just discovered that you can control it from SETTINGS.